# Fastest method to insert numbers into sql server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT TOP 1000000 row_number() over(ORDER by sv.number) AS num
INTO numbertest
from master..spt_values sv CROSS JOIN master..spt_values sv2


SELECT TOP 1000000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO NumberTest
    FROM master..spt_values sv1
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values s2
```

I've come across two methods to insert 1 to 1000000 numbers in a table which works perfectly but doesn't insert 1 to 1000000 sequentially? how can i insert sequentially with fast insertion rate?

Comment: dose not inserts or does not shows??

Comment: How are you validating that it is not sequential? Are you then running `SELECT num FROM dbo.NumberTest` without using an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Since tables have *no* inherent order, "sequentially" is ill-defined at best. If you end up with a table that contains each of the numbers between 1 and 1000000, inclusive, once and only once, then the queries are working correctly.

Comment: Doesn't creating a clustered index on the column sort the records to be in the same order?

Comment: @BobVale - a clustered index places similar items close to one another (but not necessarily, strictly, sorted in terms of disk layout), but has no (defined) effect on the order in which rows are retrieved. It's documented properties are its benefits to searches (especially range searches).

Answer (score 0):

what I understood that you need to add/insert rows with serial number 1 to 10,00,000 (ten lac rows)

your two command seems select command instead of insert command

do really required to add serial number field in one of your filed
or
you can run query to any existing table to get result with serial number like

for eg, table name : employee
        filed name : name
              Note : no fileds existing like SerialNumber

you can run a command to get output with serial number

e.g. select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by employee.name) as SerialNumber, Employee.name from employee

your result will be like

SerialNumber     name
1                abc
2                xyz

Answer (score 0):

I have table Numbers in my database that i fill with the following query.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NUMBERS] (
    [number] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
);

set Identity_insert dbo.Numbers oN

declare 
  @row_count int,
  @target_rows int

set @target_rows  = 1048576
set @row_count    = null

while ( 1 = 1 ) begin
  if ( @row_count is null ) begin
    insert into Numbers ( [number] ) values ( 1 )
  end
  else begin
    insert into Numbers ( [number] ) 
    select [number] = [number] + @row_count
    from Numbers
  end

  set @row_count = isnull( @row_count, 0 ) + @@rowcount

  if ( @row_count >= @target_rows ) begin
    break  
  end
end
```